For a densely defined operator $A:X\to Y$ with $X$ and $Y$ different Hilbert spaces, is $A$ closable still equivalent to densely defined adjoint?
I know that for a densely defined linear operator $A:\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is Hilbert, $A$ is closable if and only if $A^*$ is densely defined.
What about $A:X\to Y$ when $X$ and $Y$ are different hilbert spaces? I've managed to prove that $A^*$ is densely defined implies $A$ is closable. What about the other implication?

Both implications are proved in Chapter X, Proposition 1.6(b) of "A Course in Functional Analysis" by Conway.
Here is a proof of the implication you are asking about based on the proposition mentioned above. You can use the relation
\begin{equation}
{\rm Gra} \, A^{*} = (J({\rm Gra} \, A))^{\perp}
\end{equation}
which is valid for any densely defined linear operator $A$, where $J:X\times Y \to Y\times X$ is defined by $J(x,y) := (-y,x)$. Note that $J^{*} = J^{-1}$ because $J$ is a unitary isomorphism.
Now suppose in addition that $A$ is closable. Let $y_{0}\in ({\rm Dom} \, A^{*})^{\perp}$. If $y\in {\rm Dom} \, A^{*}$ then
\begin{equation}
((y, A^{*}y), (y_{0},0) )_{Y\times X} = (y,y_{0})_{Y} + (A^{*}y, 0)_{X} = 0.
\end{equation}
It follows that
\begin{equation}
(y_{0},0) \in ({\rm Gra} \, A^{*})^{\perp} = (J({\rm Gra} \, A) )^{\perp \perp} = \overline{J ({\rm Gra} \, A)} = J(\overline{{\rm Gra} \, A})
\end{equation}
and so
\begin{equation}
(0, -y_{0}) = J^{*}(y_{0}, 0) \in J^{*}J(\overline{{\rm Gra} \, A }) = \overline{{\rm Gra} \, A}.
\end{equation}
Since $A$ is closable one has that $\overline{{\rm Gra} \, A}$ is the graph of a linear operator. So it follows that $-y_{0} = 0$ or equivalently $y_{0} = 0$. Hence $({\rm Dom} \, A^{*})^{\perp} = \{0\}$ and therefore $A^{*}$ is densely defined.
